# Any standards or limits for Voltage Angle value of MV system?

Tags: voltage, stability, power-quality

Are there any standards or regulations that specify allowable range or permissible limits for voltage angle value? For example, 7° of voltage angle exists at MV voltage level, so is it harmful for power system?

[image]

Comment: The 7 degree angle is the number of degrees relative to some fixed reference at zero degrees OR, it could be implying that the power factor is not quite unity. Either of which cannot be determined from the information in your question as far as I can tell.